# Read-modify-write an _Atomic volatile uint64 on a 32-bit platform

Tags: c, atomic, volatile, c11

I have an instance of a struct, which lives in mmap'd shared memory, accessible by several child processes.

```
struct counter_stats {
    _Atomic volatile uint64_t packets;
    _Atomic volatile uint64_t bytes;
};
```

The modifying code is:

```
counter->packets++; 
counter->bytes += rxnum;
```

Are `_Atomic` and `volatile` sufficient to ensure that the `++` and `+=` operations occur atomically, on 32 bit (and 64 bit) ARM and x86 platforms?

(There will be multiple child processes writing to the same counter, at the same time, in shared memory.)

Comment: Isn't it guaranteed by the definition of `_Atomic` in the C11?

Comment: @AlexLop. I'm not sure.  If so, why do `atomic_compare_exchange()` and friends exist?

Comment: `atomic_compare_exchange()` can be applied on two different variables, for example if you want to compare and exchange atomically values of `packets` and `bytes`